# Where to add logic validation

Tags: laravel, rest, eloquent, laravel-8

I am having an endpoint that submits a user's rating for a salon. I want to validate that one user can only have one rating for a salon.

In which layer am i supposed to put this validation logic? Are policies a valid option or are they only used for authorization validation?

Comment: It depends on the project structure. If the rating happens on a salon specific page, you could use a middleware to block the access. Other than that you could simply validated the submission inputs with custom validation rules.

Comment: you could very well use the authorization system for this if you would like

Answer (score -1):

You can add this validation using a form request. You can create this by using the following Artisan command

```
php artisan make:request NameOfRequest
```

In your controller, instead of calling the normal validator, you can then attach the request to your function as below

```
//Remember to pull your request into the file
use App\Http\Requests\NameOfRequest;

//Controller function

public function foo(NameOfRequest $request){

//anything that gets has passed validation
}
```

Lastly, in your request, use the validation rules which will satisfy your condition

Below what does the trick is the validation rule "required_if". This will simply check if the rating is null for that particular user on a salon, then rating is required, else, means the user already rated the salon.

```
public function rules(){
  return [
    'rating' => 'required|digitsBetween:1,5|required_if:rating,null',
  ]
}
```

You can see more on the documentation [on this link to Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if)